# Why do I need this. keyword to reference a variable with the same name?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

Good evening,

This is my first post on stack overflow. I'm a newbie in programming and I can do many things in C++ - a language I love.
However, recently I've moved on to javascript with the mission of getting hired.

I'm creating a snake game and I'm automatizing its moves.
I just do not understand why a variable I created inside a function, just above a few if statements, isn't
used **inside** the statements. I had to use this. keyword to change its state.
Thank you!

```
document.getElementById("action").addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  let interval = null; // the culprit

  if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(ArrowDown, 1000);
  } else if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(ArrowRight, 1000);
  } else if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(ArrowUp, 1000);
  } else if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(ArrowLeft, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: The variable *would* be used if you omitted the `this.` everywhere, but the problem is that it's always `null` where you use it. If you wanted a static variable, whose state is preserved across multiple calls to the event handler, you would need to move the variable definition *outside* of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this.interval` and `let interval` are not the same thing at all.

The first is a property of whatever object [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is, and the second is a [block-scoped local variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) with a lifetime of just that function; just like a local function (without `static`) would have in C++.

Since you're using a regular `function()` (and not an arrow function), the caller decides what `this` is bound to at call time (see the aforelinked `this` page).

Comment: The "caller" here is the event source for the listener.  So what is `this` in a keydown event listener for a DOM element?

Comment: The best way to figure it out is to `console.log(this)`. I'd wager it's the global object (window).

Comment: bzzzzzt.  It's the DOM object that originated the event.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers! The problem with null initialized variables in js is that I can't assign values to a null container wich (doesn't exist) only by manually setting it to value 0 or any other value before using the variable to store anything else in it. Learned that the hard way.